# C# Using Generic Class without Specifying Type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class I have created as so:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T>
{
    public T Model
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }        
}
```

And at some point in my code I want to do something with anything of MyClass type. Something like:

```
private void MyMethod(object param)
{
    myClassVar = param as MyClass;
    param.Model....etc
}
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to make MyClass be a subclass of something (MyClassBase) or implement an interface (IMyClass)?

Comment: Most probably you should consider making your parameter have a specific type to avoid casting. `MyMethod` might also be a candidate for a generic method, for example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe what you are need is to make MyMethod method generic and add constraint on its type parameter:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void Foobar();
}

class MyClass<T>
{
    public T Model
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
}

private void MyMethod<T>(MyClass<T> param) where T : IMyInterface
{
    param.Model.Foobar();
}
```

Comment: +1 This should do what the OP wants. I'm not sure the interface is necessary unless they want to do something with the Model.

Answer (score 6):

No.

You need to inherit a non-generic base class or implement a non-generic interface.

Note that you won't be able to use the `Model` property, since it cannot have a type (unless you constrain it to a base type and implement an untyped property explicitly).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need. If type of generic class is undefined you need to create generic interface or using base-class...